# How to trouble shoot SOQL invalid input error in Mule4

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft, soql

I faced a strange issue that the app can be executed successfully in Mule DEV/QA server but throws SALESFORCE:INVALID_INPUT in the PRD server

Mule Dev/QA servers are standalone of runtime 4.3.0, which connects Salesforce QA env. Mule PRD server is standalone of runtime 4.3.0 which connects Salesforce PRD env.

The app is promoted from Dev to PRD via branches in Git, so the SOQL executed are the same across servers.

SOQL below (removed many fields to make it shorter):

```
SELECT CAST__c, Competitor_Currency__c FROM specification__c WHERE (recordTypeName__c LIKE 'interior%' OR recordTypeName__c LIKE 'Exterior%') AND ((Status__c = 'Pricing Requested' AND statusChangeDateTime__c > 2021-09-17T01:35:00.011-04:00) OR (Status__c = 'Pricing Provided' AND approvalDateTime__c > 2021-09-17T01:35:00.011-04:00))
```

I am wondering something is different between Salesforce PRD and QA env, but the Salesforce team said they can execute the SOQL without issue directly in SF PRD.

There is a KB online below, but it is not the same as mine, which is for the MIME type of application/java, and the minutes in my example is not 00
https://mulesoftprm.force.com/s/article/Salesforce-SOQL-Query-throws-SALESFORCE-INVALID-INPUT-with-DateTime

Can anyone share any idea how this can happen? any way to find out the root cause? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually caused by some fields in the SOQL query statement have different permission settings in Salesforce UAT and PRD env.

After SF team updated the permission settings on those fields in PRD, the issue is fixed. The error "SALESFORCE:INVALID_INPUT" is not quite accurate shown in Mulesoft log.

Answer (score 0):

This looks exactly like what the KB article you referenced describes. Looking at your query I don't see any input parameter to the query, so maybe the error is being caused by the literal timestamps having zero seconds. Try passing them as input parameters and assign them as strings outside the query as the KB suggests. Date/time format conversion issues are common also with databases and need to be taken extra care in most languages.

Example:

```
... statusChangeDateTime__c > :changeTime ...


...

changeTime: ('2021-09-17T01:35:00.011-04:00' as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"}) as String
```

Comment: The parameter is for "statusChangeDateTime__c " and "approvalDateTime__c", which have been replaced by literals by me, as the value has been logged before parsing the SOQL. Also to have this query executed by SFDC team, I replaced parameter by the value from the log. The root cause in the KB is dataweave issue when coerce datatime to MIME type as application/java.

Comment: Please share the operation as it is in the flow and the parameters. Otherwise we are not looking at the same problem. Note that every expression in Mule 4 is a DataWeave expression, even to define parameters in the connector operation.